# how do install windows 8 in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows

I want to install windows 8 alongside Ubuntu (my default and only operating system), but i am not sure how. can someone explain? can I virtualize windows 8 or is there another way. I want windows 8 mostly for staying ahead of the game and helping people with their windows 8 questions. so far, I have installed virtual box, but it has given me an error. again, I don't want to get rid of Ubuntu (I love Ubuntu), I just want to have the other operating system there if I need it.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would run Windows 8 in a virtual machine, like VMware. VMware player or workstation is better then virtual box. If you try to install Windows 8 along side Ubuntu, you will have to restore grub2. Restoring grub2 is a pain.